# php add method from object class to another object class

Tags: php, class, object

i have a object like this:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['DATA']
```

that contains an array of `Class->Method`:

```
array (
  'DATA' => 
  array (
    'USERDATAMANAGER' => 
    Class_UserdataManager::__set_state(array(
    )),
    'PRODDATAMANAGER' => 
    Class_ProddataManager::__set_state(array(
    )),
  ),
)
```

i create a new object, of type class Like this:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] = new class;
```

**i cant but need pass all the methods of the first object, ignoring the class of origin to the class i create on fly, and that allows me to execute the functions from the class declared on the fly. 
does this exist in php 7.0 or is there any way to achieve this reach??
It would be like cloning the methods of several classes to a single and new class.**

Answer for @Damian Dziaduch comments

the piece of code that i used to Dynamically Instance all class file from a directory is this, and populate the first object with instance of class:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']= new class;    
foreach (CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'] as $key => $name) {
    if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
        $name  = basename($name);
        $name  = preg_replace('#\.php#', '', $name);
        $names = explode(".", $name);
        foreach ($names as $key => $namesr) {
            $names[$key] = ucfirst(strtolower($namesr));
        }
        $name                                         = implode('_', $names);
        $NamesClass                                   = $name . 'Manager';
        $InstanceClass                                = strtoupper(preg_replace('#\Class_#', '', $NamesClass));
        CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['DATA'][$InstanceClass] = $this->$InstanceClass = new $NamesClass();
    }
}
```

the result of it is the Array printed at start of the post `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['DATA']` .

if you see at start of foreach i have the new class declaration to use, in loop, how can i populate `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']` in the loop, it with all methods of the first object instance, and make it executables?

that i whant (not work):

```
foreach ( CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['DATA'] as $key => $value ) {
    CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] .= Clone($value);
}
```

`$value` represent where is  storing the methods:

```
 ::__set_state(array()),
```

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow, your question is not clear. could you try to reformulate ? or may provide more detailled example ?

Comment: @Yanis-git What part do they have difficulty understanding?

Comment: Do you want to create anynomous class and assign it to `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']`?

Comment: your actual issue, what have you try so far and where you get stoke. You can [provide live code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) which really help to understand.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch yes but i need populate it with all function of the first object class.

Comment: @Yanis-git If I upload the example you want, this would have many files; I'm giving you the current data in output of the variables that.

Comment: So you want to extends the original class :) It is possible via `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] = new class extends Class_UserdataManager { /* body here */ };`

Comment: what damian prupose looks to be the closest thing to your facing issues

Comment: thank you @DamianDziaduch but i not have `Class_UserdataManager { /* body here */ };` i have this first object class with intances formated in and array access: `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['DATA'];`

Comment: how can i extends multiple time, and looping the first object.

Comment: Ah I get it finally. So `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS = new class implements ArrayAccess { /* you have to implement the methods from the interface here */ };` probably will fill your needs

Comment: More here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: @DamianDziaduch create an answer to work (comment) with it plz.

Comment: @walternuñez I have read again what you have added and I can see clearly that your problem is to create a copy of the object, did try the `clone` operator? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested.

Not sure whether this will fill you requirements... The question is whether you are able to overwrite the `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS`

```
<?php

CORE::$ObjClassInstABS = new class extends \ArrayIterator {
    private $container = [];

    public function __construct(array $container)
    {
        $this->container = [
            'ABS' => [
                'DATA' => [
                    'USERDATAMANAGER' => new class {},
                    'PRODDATAMANAGER' => new class {},
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
};
```

Comment: i have added a block of code for you in the original question plz check it.

Comment: @walternuñez is this still required?

Comment: @i have solve this issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190995/10771500